# PHP - Unpack module with hexstring

Tags: php, upload, hex

What I am basically trying to achieve is:

1. read the uploaded file (image, exe etc) as binary data
2. convert it to hexstring
3. check if it contains a string

I have tinkered around and managed to write a code that does what is said above, however, my current problem is as follows:

The string "needle" which converts to "6e6565646c65" in hex; does not match in the file if the letters are capitalized (case-sensitive). For example, it wouldn't match with "Needle" or "needlE".

So, how do I check if a string exists in a file while being case-insensitive? I have tried NOT changing the file to hexstring and checking the raw data, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to get it to work.

This is the code I have right now:

```
$hex = unpack("H*", file_get_contents($filetmp));
$hex = current($hex);
if (strpos(strtolower($hex), '6e6565646c65'){

//string "needle" matches in the file

}
```

Any idea on what could be done using PHP? It could be an entirely different method, I don't mind, I'll study it.

Comment: Converting the file/search text to hex doesn't make much sense, is there a specific reason you're wanting/trying to do that?

Comment: I got an answer below which solves the problem. No specific reason, that's how I handle bytes in C so I just did the same with PHP.

Comment: Ahh okay, well in that case you could also do something like: `$contains_needle = (stripos(file_get_contents($filetmp), 'needle') !== false);` and `$contains_needle` will be true/false as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try checking the needle against the lowercase file data:

```
$hex = unpack("H*", strtolower(file_get_contents($filetmp)));
$hex = current($hex);
if (strpos($hex, '6e6565646c65' !== false) {
    //found
}
```

Also, check for `false` as `strpos` will return a falsey `0` if it is found at the beginning.

Comment: I see, so that's how PHP variables work? I'm used to C# so I thought for sure I had to convert types in some way. Thanks, that did the trick, appreciate it.